# Ansible ad hoc commands only work as sudo unless i'm in the hosts directory

Tags: ansible, ansible-ad-hoc

I'm trying to work through getting started with ansible.  When I try to run ad hoc commands with ansible, such as `ansible all -m ping` I have to either be in the same folder as my hosts file `~/Development/ansible/` or use sudo.  I'm getting ready to move forward with learning playbooks but I feel like this is going to come back as a problem at some point.

If I try to run the command outside of that folder without sudo I get this message

```
<XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: Joe
<XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX> REMOTE_MODULE ping
server | FAILED => Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/runner/__init__.py", line 586, in _executor
    exec_rc = self._executor_internal(host, new_stdin)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/runner/__init__.py", line 789, in _executor_internal
    return self._executor_internal_inner(host, self.module_name, self.module_args, inject, port, complex_args=complex_args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/runner/__init__.py", line 1036, in _executor_internal_inner
    result = handler.run(conn, tmp, module_name, module_args, inject, complex_args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/runner/action_plugins/normal.py", line 62, in run
    return self.runner._execute_module(conn, tmp, module_name, module_args, inject=inject, complex_args=complex_args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/runner/__init__.py", line 470, in _execute_module
    ) = self._configure_module(conn, module_name, args, inject, complex_args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/runner/__init__.py", line 1351, in _configure_module
    module_path = utils.plugins.module_finder.find_plugin(module_name, module_suffixes)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/utils/plugins.py", line 176, in find_plugin
    full_paths = (os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path))
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/Joe/library/Saved Application State/jp.co.trendy.sdformatter.savedState'
```

I've done a lot of searching around but haven't had much luck finding a solution.

Here is my `~/.ansible.cfg` file

```
# config file for ansible -- http://ansible.com/
# ==============================================

# nearly all parameters can be overridden in ansible-playbook 
# or with command line flags. ansible will read ANSIBLE_CONFIG,
# ansible.cfg in the current working directory, .ansible.cfg in
# the home directory or /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg, whichever it
# finds first

[defaults]

# some basic default values...

inventory      = ~/Development/ansible/hosts
```

And, here is my hosts file

```
server     ansible_ssh_host=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX     ansible_ssh_user=Joe     ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be not an Ansible problem but a permission issue with a software called [SD Card Formatter from Trendy Corp](http://www.trendy.co.jp/sd/en/p_formatter.html). I don't know why this would be triggered when you run Ansible though.

The permissions of all the files in your library should get fixed by "repair permissions" in the Disk Utility Tool. Alternatively make sure the files and folders in `/Users/Joe/library/Saved Application State/jp.co.trendy.sdformatter.savedState` belong to user `Joe`: `chown -R Joe:Joe /Users/Joe/library/Saved Application State/jp.co.trendy.sdformatter.savedState`. If you don't care about this application, deleting the mentioned folder completely should do it too.

Comment: Thanks!  Disk utility didn't do the trick, but the changing ownership on the folder did.